# GARCH Parameters Standard Errors

Tags: garch

How do you compute the standard errors of a GARCH model estimated with MLE ?

[This paper](http://www.stern.nyu.edu/rengle/GARCH101.PDF) references a method by Bollerslev-Wooldridge: *[...] and computed standard errors using the robust method of Bollerslev-Wooldridge*

Do you know of an implementation of this method (whatever the language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fGarch` package function `garchFit()` provides this functionality if you call it with `cond.dist = 'QMLE'`. Check out the documentation on the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fGarch/index.html).

> "QMLE" stands for Quasi-Maximum Likelihood Estimation, which assumes normal distribution and uses robust standard errors for inference. Bollerslev and Wooldridge (1992) proved that if the mean and the volatility equations are correctly specified, the QML estimates are consistent and asymptotically normally distributed...

The documentation references the following book: Econometric Theory and Methods - Russell Davidson & James G. Mackinnon (section 10.3 and 10.4) and has some more details.

Comment: The documentation references the following book: Econometric Theory and Methods - Russell Davidson & James G. Mackinnon (section 10.3 and 10.4)

Comment: Good addition, added